# Deal with .png image when Deserialization and Serialization JSON data using C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, png, jpeg

I am trying to Deserialize and serialize json data from Wikipedia API. At first I need to Deserilize some particular data like Title,Extract, Images, Co-ordinates etc.After Deserialization , I need to serialize this data again to get resulted output. But which serialization I am having problem that is the Wikipedia API there are some images in png format. But in my code I can convert only jpg image to hash format. so when .png file occurred, it goes to exception handling and nothing shows as output. I would like to know how can I write my code which can convert both jpg and png image. My code is as follows-

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        var response = client.DownloadString("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&redirects=1&generator=geosearch&prop=extracts|coordinates|pageimages&ggslimit=20&ggsradius=1000&ggscoord=48.47|9.11&&formatversion=2&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exlimit=20&coprop=type|dim|globe&colimit=20&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=400&pilimit=20"); 
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

        List<Poi> poi = new List<Poi>();

        foreach (var page in json.query.pages) //foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'List_Places_Geo.RootObject' because 'List_Places_Geo.RootObject' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
        {
            Poi obj = new Poi();
            obj.Title = page.title;//what to write in this line to get the title;
            obj.Description =page.extract ;

            var Image = new PoiImage();
            var ImgfirstKey = page.thumbnail.source;
            Image.ImageID = string.Format("{0:X}.jpg", ImgfirstKey.GetHashCode());

            obj.Images = new List<PoiImage> {Image};

            obj.Lat = page.coordinates.First().lat;
            obj.Lon = page.coordinates.First().lon;

            poi.Add(obj);
        }

        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(poi, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

My Wikipedia api looks like this-

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&redirects=1&generator=geosearch&prop=extracts|coordinates|pageimages&ggslimit=20&ggsradius=1000&ggscoord=52.5243700|13.4105300&&formatversion=2&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exlimit=20&coprop=type|dim|globe&colimit=20&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=400&pilimit=20
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Code. Might be helpful for you . Get Images Directly from *Path* (**You will definitely get a path of Each `Image`** ) and Change it into `Base64` encoded `String` and pass it in `JSONObject`.

At other end decode it using `Base64` Class decoder and Write it as a file. 
Here a `code` to `encode` the Image Directly from `Path`

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Path))
    {                 
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }                  
    }
```